# Raising Javascript confirm box from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to raise a Javascript confirm box from code behind.

I am using the following syntax

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "key", "javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');", true);
```

It is throwing an error:

> return statement out of function

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `return`, you are not returning this value anywhere. The `RegisterStartupScript` is executing the function in the global context:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    this, 
    GetType(), 
    "key", 
    "confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');", 
    true
);
```

But this is probably something you should not even be doing on the server. You should ask for confirmation **BEFORE** calling the server side. By subscribing to the `onclick` javascript handler of the corresponding control that is raising the server side event to delete.

For example if you have a delete link:

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    ID="DeleteButton" 
    runat="server" 
    CausesValidation="False"
    CommandName="Delete" 
    Text="Delete"
    OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');" 
/>
```

Comment: yeah sorry..done..i got very fast response from Darin..it did not allowed me to mark as answer for 10 mins. i thought of marking it later.done.now..thanks..Darin and Max

Comment: yeah Darin..I agree with you ..it should be done on client side..thanks again